# Can I have a form_dropdown within a javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

Hi I am using codeigniter framework. I am having a javascript to to create a table row dynamically when I click a button.
I need to have a dropdown inside a table cell that is added dynamically. Here is the code I tried so far.

```
function displayResult() {
<?php

      $attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => '');
      $options_employee = array('' => "Select");
      foreach ($employee as $row)
      {
        $options_employee[$row['first_name']] = $row['first_name'];
      }

      ?>
     var something='<?php echo form_dropdown('employee', $options_employee, set_value('employee[]'), 'class="span2"');?>';
     alert(something);

    var row = document.getElementById("test").insertRow(-1);
    row.innerHTML = '<td><div>'+something+'</div></td><td><input type="text" name="start_time[]" value="" style="width:35px;"/></td><td><input type="text" name="pid[]" style="width:35px;"/></td><td><input type="text" name="description[]" class="description" value="" style="width:145px;"/></td><td><input type="text" class="type" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td><td><input type="text" class="qty_prch" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td><td><input type="text" class="qty_used" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td>';
}
```

When button is clicked I call this `displayResult()`. I am getting **2 errors** in my console.

```
1.Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
2.Uncaught ReferenceError: displayResult is not defined
```

Can someone help me? Please help me fix this code.

```js
function displayResult() { <? php

  $attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => '');
  $options_employee = array('' => "Select");
  foreach($employee as $row) {
    $options_employee[$row['first_name']] = $row['first_name'];
  }

  ?>
  var something = '<?php echo form_dropdown('
  employee ', $options_employee, set_value('
  employee[]
  '), '
  class = "span2"
  ');?>';
  alert(something);

  var row = document.getElementById("test").insertRow(-1);
  row.innerHTML = '<td><div>' + something + '</div></td><td><input type="text" name="start_time[]" value="" style="width:35px;"/></td><td><input type="text" name="pid[]" style="width:35px;"/></td><td><input type="text" name="description[]" class="description" value="" style="width:145px;"/></td><td><input type="text" class="type" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td><td><input type="text" class="qty_prch" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td><td><input type="text" class="qty_used" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td>';
}
```

```html
<div id="form">
  <!-- div form starts here.its for add table  -->
  <table id="test">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:80px;">
          employee
        </td>
        <td style="width:35px;">
          start time
        </td>
        <td style="width:35px;">
          id
        </td>
        <td style="width:145px;">
          Description
        </td>
        <td style="width:45px;">
          Type
        </td>
        <td style="width:45px;">
          qty prch
        </td>
        <td style="width:45px;">
          qty used
        </td>
        <td style="width:70px;">
          Price
        </td>
        <td style="width:70px;">
          discount
        <td style="width:70px;">
          Tax
        </td>
        <td style="width:70px;">
          Total
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <?php echo form_dropdown( 'employee', $options_employee, set_value( 'employee[]'), 'class="span2"');?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="start_time[]" value="" style="width:35px;" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="pid[]" value="" style="width:35px;" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="description[]" class="description" value="" style="width:145px;" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="type[]" class="type" style="width:45px;" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="qty_prch[]" class="qty_prch" style="width:45px;" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="qty_used[]" class="qty_used" style="width:45px;" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="price[]" class="price" style="width:70px;" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="discount[]" class="discount" style="width:70px;" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="tax[]" class="tax" style="width:70px;" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="total[]" class="total" style="width:70px;" />
        </td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>



  </table>

  <div id="add_row">
    <button onClick="displayResult()" class="add_r"></button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Show us the generated HTML of this PHP script.

Comment: place your function `displayResult()` in head section

Comment: It is in head section but still it do not work @JSantosh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me. Thank you all for your support !!

```
function displayResult() {
<?php

      $attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => '');
      $options_employee = array('' => "Select");
      foreach ($employee as $row)
      {
        $options_employee[$row['first_name']] = $row['first_name'];
      }
    $dropdown = form_dropdown('employee', $options_employee, set_value('employee[]'), 'class="span2"');

      ?>

    var complex = <?php echo json_encode($dropdown); ?>;

    var row = document.getElementById("test").insertRow(-1);
    row.innerHTML = 
        '<td><div>'+complex+'</div></td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" name="start_time[]" value="" style="width:35px;"/></td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" name="pid[]" style="width:35px;"/></td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" name="description[]" class="description" value="" style="width:145px;"/></td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" class="type" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" class="qty_prch" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" class="qty_used" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your single `'` to double `"`

your code is `var something='<?php echo form_dropdown('employee', $options_employee, set_value('employee[]'), 'class="span2"');?>';`

because when javascript start reading this line
`var something='<?php echo form_dropdown('employee'` it seems statement end here `('e` near `'` after `dropdown('`

you should use something like that

```
var something='<?php echo form_dropdown("employee", $options_employee, set_value("employee[]"), \'class="span2"\');?>';
```

sorry for my bad english

Comment: why that should be changed? any reasons?

Comment: I got my results and answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

In your code Snippet on the first line :

```
function displayResult() { <? php
```

there is a space between `<? and php`

Remove that and retry.